# Order by in ADF TreeTable

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, treetable

Is it posible to set sortproperty in a TreeTable in ADF?
I have a viewcriteria, with a order by clause in the query.

The the TreeTable doesn't show the items in the correct order.
Is this known, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! The iterator had a sort property set. Deleted the sort property, and the 'order by' clause works like a charm :)